# How to add multiple chars in .endsWith() Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have an expression `when` in my code, which does:

```
when{
    currentOpperand.text.toString().endsWith("+") || 
    currentOpperand.text.toString().endsWith("-") || 
    currentOpperand.text.toString().endsWith("÷") ||
    currentOpperand.text.toString().endsWith("×") ||
    currentOpperand.text.toString().endsWith(".") ||
    currentOpperand.text.toString().endsWith("")
    ->{
        currentOpperand.text = currentOpperand.text.toString() + ""
    }
```

I want to make this code shorter, like:

```
when{
    currentOpperand.text.toString().endsWith("+", "-", "÷", "×", ".", "") ->{
        currentOpperand.text = currentOpperand.text.toString() + ""
    }
```

But android studio gives me an error:

> ***None of the following functions can be called with the argument supplied***

If it's possible, comment please another way to do these using things like: `lastIndexOfAny` or etc. (I want to do this action in any way possible with the shortest result in code)

Comment: You can create regex and use matches() to do your work

Comment: `endsWith("")` will always return `true` for any string. And what is the point of this expression `currentOpperand.text = currentOpperand.text.toString() + ""`?

Comment: i'm making calculator,
if to don't write something like
(X)++-*/(Y)
when string ends with + - * or /, you can't write any other operations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
var doesExist = currentOpperand.text.last().toString() in arrayOf("+", "-", "÷", "×", ".", "")

when{
    doesExist ->{
    currentOpperand.text = currentOpperand.text.toString() + ""
    }
}
```

But the question is:  `currentOpperand.text = currentOpperand.text.toString() + ""` is redundant, of no use. Why you're doing so?

Comment: and how to use this in my when expression?

Comment: @Lλmbdλ edited my answer, but what you're doing in the function is redundant

Answer (score 2):

You can use the extension function. Here is how it looks:

```
fun String.endsWithMulti(vararg chars: Char): Boolean
{
    chars.forEach {
        if (endsWith(it))
        {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

fun main()
{
    // Test
    println("TEST_+".endsWithMulti('+', '-', '/', '*')) // true
    println("TEST_-".endsWithMulti('+', '-', '/', '*')) // true
    println("TEST_O".endsWithMulti('+', '-', '/', '*')) // false
}
```

So your `when` statement will look something like this:

```
when
{
    stringYouWantToCheck.endsWithMulti('+', '-', '÷', '×', '.') ->
    {
        // do something
    }
    else ->
    {
        // string doesn't end with '+', '-', '÷', '×', '.'
    }
}
```

---

As @IR42 mentioned in the comment You can simplify `endsWithMulti`

```
fun String.endsWithMulti(vararg chars: Char): Boolean
{
    return chars.any {
        endsWith(it)
    }
}
```

Comment: you can simplify your `endsWithMulti`:  `return chars.any { endsWith(it) }`

Comment: @IR42 Yeah, I haven't known about this. I have edited answer and added Your solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use regex:

```
   val regex = """\+|\.|\-|×|÷| $""".toRegex()  
   val matched = regex.containsMatchIn(currentOpperand.text.toString()) 
   if(matched)
       currentOpperand.text = currentOpperand.text.toString() + "" //this line is Questionable，maybe you should do other things.
```

Comment: You want `(\+|\.|\-|×|÷| )$` - otherwise, it only checks for `<space>$`. The other chars can be anywhere with a match